# String.replaceAll variation

Tags: java

Is there a quick way to replace all of some pattern occurrences with data derived from the matched pattern?

For example, if I wanted to replace all occurrences of a number within a string with the same number padded to fixed length with 0s.

In this case if the length is 4, then `ab3cd5` would become `ab0003cd0005`.

My idea was using a StringBuilder and 2 patterns: one would get all numbers and the other would get everything that is not a number, and appending the matches to the builder by the index the matches were found.

I think there might be something simpler.

Comment: if you're sure that the number will always be a single digit then it's pretty easy to do a regex, but if your fill has to depend on the length of the pre-existing number then I don't think there's a regex y way to do that (though I'll be curious what others say).

Answer (score 2):

You can probably achieve what you're after using `appendReplacement` and `appendTail`, something like this:

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

```
String REGEX = "(\\d+)";
String INPUT = "abc3def45";
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0000");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT); // get a matcher object
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb,formatter.format(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))));
}

m.appendTail(sb);

String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly how many zeros you want to pad before any single number, then something like this should work:

```
String text = "ab3cd5";
text = text.replaceAll("\\d","0000$0");
System.out.println(text);
```

Otherwise:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()){
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()))); 
}
matcher.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The format `%04d` means: an integer, padded by zero up to a length of 4.